# Vectorized Creation of 2D Array from 3D array Given 1D Array of Indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Given an array, *x*, of shape *(2,n,m)* and a set of indexes *[i,j]* where *i,j < n*, I am trying to obtain an array of shape *(2,m)* where the first array is at index *[0,i]* and the second array is at index *[1,j]*. This is a test case for generalizing to an array of shape *(b,n,m)* and a set of indexes of length *b*.

The obvious choice for this operation is *np.choose*, but this is acting differently than expected. We want to pair the row *i* of the first array with the row *j* of the second array. However, when using *np.choose([i,j],x)*, *np.choose* pairs the first **column** from the *array* with index *i*  with the second column from the *array* with index *j* (which can be seen in the code below) to get an array of shape *(n,m)*. Obviously this task is easily performed with a for loop, but because of the use case (within Keras as a custom function of a tensor, where iteration is prohibited) I cannot do this. Is there a vectorized way of performing this operation, using either the Keras Backend functions or Numpy? I'm currently looking at using "map" to do this, and will update with my own answer if I figure it out.

Here's a code snippet showing you how np.choose handles the *(2,n,m)* array:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> x = np.random.rand(2,4,2)
>>> choices = [3,1]
>>> np.choose(choices,x)
    ValueError: invalid entry in choice array
>>> np.choose([0,0],x)
    #Returns an array with x[0,:,0] and x[0,:,1] in shape(4,2)
```

Comment: Do you have a working loop code?

Comment: @Divakar Yes I do, but it's for the overall task that I'm performing (finding the maximum probability output for batch "b" containing "n" separate softmax outputs). This is the last step in the vectorization of that function. Should I provide the code for the overall function, as well? Seemed irrelevant at the point, but I guess it provides a bit more context into what's happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). On an example :

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.random.randint(0,10,(2,4,3))
```

`x` is :

```
[[[0 4 1]
  [8 8 1]
  [3 3 6]
  [4 7 8]]

 [[7 1 2]
  [5 9 9]
  [0 4 0]
  [7 8 3]]]
```

Now `x[[0,1],[3,1],:]` is :

```
[[4 7 8]
 [5 9 9]]
```

This can be extended to a `(b,m,n)` problem :

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.random.randint(0,10,(100,200,300))
choices= np.random.randint(0,200,(100))

def loop():
    res=np.empty((100,300),int)
    for i in range(100):
        res[i]=x[i,choices[i]]
    return res
```

And some performance tests :

```
In [30]: %timeit loop()
10000 loops, best of 3: 140 µs per loop

In [31]: %timeit x[arange(100),choices,:]
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.7 µs per loop
```

Here the indexing method is only 6 times faster than a loop, because the task 
(extraction)  cannot take advantage of the memory alignment.

Finally you can enhance the loop with just in time compilation by `loop2=numba.njit(loop)`.

```
In [32]: %timeit loop2()
10000 loops, best of 3: 32 µs per loop
```

which shows that the indexing method is optimal.

Comment: This is not vectorized - if you're given a random array of shape (b,4,3) you would have to iterate through the list of indices (which has length b) in order to use this method. 

Also, if you're trying to index into x[0,1] shouldn't the result be [8,8,1], and shouldn't [3,1] give you an out of bounds error?

Comment: No, it returns arrays indexed by [0,3,:] and [1,1,:] .   x[ a,b,:] return [x[a0,b0,:],x[a1,b1,:], etc.]

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. However, if you're given the array of indices "choices", you can't simply call x[choices,:]. In order for your code to work you have to iterate through "choices", by calling x[choices[0],choices[1],:] (in the case where b=2). We need to avoid iteration and have a general solution where b is arbitrary.

Comment: I think you can give range(b) as first indexer.

Comment: Using range(len(choices)) (which is just range(b)) works. Thanks for the help!